# Tradingview Pinescript How to use Session to get volume of the opening candle

Tags: pine-script

I am very new to Pinescript and I have a question which is probably very simple to code. I trade using the 1 minute chart on Tradingview and I want to get the volume for the opening 1 minute candle (9:30 a.m.).  Then I want to compare that volume to the volume of each 1 minute candle thereafter and if the volume of any candle after the opening candle is less than or equal to 15% of the opening candle volume, I want to color that bar blue.
I have written many Pinescript scripts over the last few years but they are all very very simple and I have never worked with Sessions before which I assume I will need to do in order to reference the opening candle's volume.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated....thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

var float refVolume = 0
var color myColor = na

bar_date_ts = timestamp(year(time),month(time),dayofmonth(time),0,0,0)
is_new_date = change(bar_date_ts)

if (is_new_date)
    refVolume := volume * 0.15

barcolor(volume <= refVolume ? color.blue : na)
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for responding to my question.  I think you are close to what I am looking for but the code is not working the way that I need.  Some of the candles are turning blue but not the ones that should. It doesn't appear to be using the first 1 minute candle at 9:30 a.m. as the reference volume.

Comment: On which ticker do you run this script? It will work on any ticker that trades only during RTH. Not on continuous tickers, like futures.

Comment: It seems that I need to specify the trading session.....t = time(period, "0930-1600").....something like that somewhere because in your example code, many of the bars that turn blue are in the afterhours and premarket sessions.

Comment: I trade Nasdaq stocks from 9:30a.m. to 4:00p.m.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of a ticker it doesn't work on please?